# How to find the maximum and lowest value of a random normal or log-normal distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, math, statistics, normal-distribution

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so forgive me if I'm not in conformity with some norms. That being said, this is my problem:

Edited:
I have a continuous variable where I can only measure some points of data and I need to assess the probability curve for the maximum and lowest values between each data point. I have the std deviation and the variable works on lognormal distribution, this means the average is a log-mean and the std deviation is multiplicative.

Example:

> Assuming a car's speed is normally distributed and there are no traffic laws, at 10 AM the car is travelling at the speed of 40 MPH, at 11 AM he is travelling at 60 MPH, the standard deviation is a 10% change of its speed every hour. There is this 1h blackout in between where you have no information, but you should be able to estimate: the more probable highest speed the car achieved in this time, the more probable lowest speed, and somehow a probability distribution of everything in between. You can even assume Its the least unlikely probability that its speed at 10 AM was its lowest speed and at 11 AM was it highest speed in the period (if the car speed is truly random at every scale you can even assume its limiting the impossible). The outcome is a lognormal distribution which could be used to simulate scenarios regarding that car.

I'm not an expert in statistics and I understand only the basics and some theory, how should I address this problem?

I'm using this on Python 3.x in case you guys know an way to address that problem there.

Comment: You do not seem to have enough information (if I understand your problem correctly). The size of the sample (the number of data points) matters--the more points, the closer the "lowest value" will be to your bottom data point. The mean also matters--if the mean is in your interval there will be many points, but if the mean is far removed there will be fewer points.

Comment: I need to estimate the highest and lowest value between each data point, individually, so its like every couple of data points gathers all information from start to finish, I cant scale down any further, a 2 point sample with the correct standard deviation of the population. From this, assuming the distribution is continuous, there should be a solution. My plan C is brute-forcing shattering the data simulating smaller data-points, scaling down the std deviation dividing by the sqr root of the new total data points (2 points become 4 by simulating 2 more).

Comment: I think you might want to take this question to stats.stackexchange.com and ask about the strictly statistical aspects of it.

Comment: I asked there but not a single reply yet. I edited the question here so it is more objective and simple. I figured it out a process to solve the problem but it is heavy process-intensive: (1) I divide the std deviation by the sqr root of X (any number between 3 and infinite) (2) I use that standard deviation to simulate X-1 data points between the 2 Im analysing (3) repeat the process N times, create a probability curve. The higher X and N the more accurate is the process.